# Simple Limit Question

Tags: real-analysis

Given: $c\in \mathbb{R} $ and $ {(a_n})$ sequence and l$\in\mathbb{R}$ and

$\forall \,\, \epsilon>0\,\,\exists\ n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\,\,\forall n>n_0$, $|a_n-l|<c\epsilon$

prove that
$\forall \,\, \epsilon>0\,$,$\,\exists\  n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \ n>n_0 \,\,|a_n-l|<\epsilon$

Comment: Hint: fix $\epsilon>0$, and use the first part to find $n_0$ corresponding to $\epsilon'=\epsilon/c$...

Comment: that is how it was proven - but now I understand - I begin a fresh proof from scratch choose an $\epsilon$ and then I show that there exist $n_0$ due to the given statement. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to realize that the epsilons in the two statements:

$\ \ \ \ $1) $\forall \,\, \epsilon>0\,\,\exists\ n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\,\,\forall n>n_0$, $|a_n-l|<c\epsilon$.

and

$\ \ \ \ $2) $\forall \,\, \epsilon>0\,$,$\,\exists\  n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \ n>n_0 \,\,|a_n-l|<\epsilon$.

are not necessarily the same. You could use any symbol you like in either of the statements to play the role of $\epsilon$. It is therefore valid and would perhaps makes things more clear to reformulate the statements as

$\ \ \ \ $1') $\forall \,\, \epsilon'>0\,\,\exists\ n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\,\,\forall n>n_0$, $|a_n-l|<c\epsilon'$.

and

$\ \ \ \ $2') $\forall \,\, \epsilon>0\,$,$\,\exists\  n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall \ n>n_0 \,\,|a_n-l|<\epsilon$.

You need to show that 2') holds if 1') holds.

**Hint**:

Note that in order for 1') to hold, we must have $c>0$. Thus,  given any $\epsilon>0$, you can, by choosing $\epsilon'$ appropriately, make $c\epsilon'=\epsilon$.

**Solution**:

We fix a value of $\epsilon >0$. Then if we set $\epsilon'=\epsilon/c$ we have $\epsilon'> 0$ (recall that $c$ must be positive). We now appeal to  1') to obtain  an $n_0$, so that  $\forall \ n>n_0 $:
$$|a_n-l|<c\epsilon'=c\cdot(\epsilon /c)=\epsilon; $$ and we are done.

Comment: exactly, it took me some time to comprehend it, but after the first answer I got it. Thank you very much for the more detailed solution.